# Why dd($request) can't get the request of TinyMCE using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, laravel-5

I don't know which the cause but I have a `tinymce` plugin with a selector which is my `textarea`. I'm trying to check if I get the request on my `textarea` which is the text editor. When I check it doesn't have any column for my `textarea` which has a id of `content` under `+request: ParameterBag`

Screenshot below.

[image: SC]

As you can see here it doesn't have any **key** which is `content` id of my textarea. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this.

Script:

```
<script>
tinymce.init
({
    selector: '#content',
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
    'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor save'
    ], //The plugins configuration option allows you to enable functionality within the editor.
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | save',
    save_enablewhendirty: true,
    height: 400,
});

function get_editor_content()
{

// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());

// Get content of a specific editor:
var selectContent = tinymce.get('content').getContent();

}

</script>
```

I can get here the value of my textarea but still don't have any idea how can I save or insert this on my database. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Form:

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route('document.create')}}">

        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "title" class = "control-label">Title:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "title" class = "form-control">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <label for = "to" class = "control-label">To:</label>
            <select onChange = "showUserOptions(this)" name = "to[]" multiple class = "form-control" id = "myUserList">

            @foreach ($result as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
            @endforeach

            </select>
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <label for = "category" class = "control-label">Category:</label>
            <select onChange = "showCategoryOptions(this)" name = "category" class = "form-control" id = "myCategory">

                <option selected disabled>Please select role</option>
                @foreach ($resultCategory as $categoryList)
                    <option value = "{{ $categoryList->id }}">{{ $categoryList->category_type }}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
            <textarea id="content"></textarea>
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="get_editor_content()">Send</button>
        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
class DocumentController extends Controller
{
public function getDocuments()
{
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();

    return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);
}

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'to' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'category' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a name to the textarea:

```
<div class = "form-group">
    <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't notice that! You're too fast. Thanks for this!